# How does terminal encoding work in vim?

Tags: vim, encoding, terminal

### In GNOME Terminal(3.4.1.1)

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ echo 你好 | iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF32BE | tee hello.txt
O`Y}
```

### In vim(7.3):

```
$ vim -N -u NONE --cmd 'set tenc=utf32 enc=utf32 fencs=utf32be' hello.txt
你好
~
~
~    

:set tenc enc fenc
  termencoding=ucs-4
  encoding=ucs-4
  fileencoding=ucs-4
```

---

The terminal cannot display `UTF32` characters.
After modifying several encoding options of Vim.
Vim still can display `UTF32` without any problems.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. You can run your command inside [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) to verify that Vim is actually writing UTF-8 to your terminal.

The help for [`'charconvert'`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/options.txt?name=v7-3-548#1383) and [`'encoding'`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/options.txt?name=v7-3-548#2590) give oblique hints as to the internal operation, but I did not find a corresponding hint that this same behavior is applied to `termencoding`. Respectively:

> Vim internally uses UTF-8 instead of UCS-2 or UCS-4.

and

> When "unicode", "ucs-2" or "ucs-4" is used, Vim internally uses utf-8.

So, we will use the [source](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse?name=v7-3-548) (version 7.3.548, specifically) to find out what is happening.

The value for the `termencoding`/`tenc` option is [stored](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/option.c?name=v7-3-548#2528) in the global variable [`p_tenc`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/option.h?name=v7-3-548#777).

- [`did_set_string_option()`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/option.c?name=v7-3-548#5625) seems to handle the setting of string-valued options.

  - When [handling `termencoding`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/option.c?name=v7-3-548#5958), it calls [`convert_setup()`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#5806) to setup `output_conv` (for converting `encoding` to `termencoding`).

    The comment for `convert_setup` gives the first hint as to what is happening:

    > Note: cannot be used for conversion from/to ucs-2 and ucs-4 (will use utf-8 instead).

    - `convert_setup` [calls](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#5821) [`convert_setup_ext()`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#5824) with TRUE for both of the {`from`,`to`}`_unicode_is_utf8` parameters.

      - When {`from`,`to`}`_unicode_is_utf8` are true (they are), it sets the local variables  {`from`,`to`}`_is_utf8` based on whether the specified encodings have the ENC_UNICODE property ([`ucs-4` does](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#254), as do all of Vim’s `utf-…` and `ucs-…` encodings).
        When it comes time to [open an `iconv`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#5921), Vim substitutes `utf-8` if {`from`,`to`}`_is_utf8` are true (in this case, they are).

Ultimately, the values of `encoding` and `termencoding` are handled in the same way here. [`utf-32` is mapped to `ucs-4`](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/mbyte.c?name=v7-3-548#385), which has ENC_UNICODE, and Vim substitutes the desired encoding with UTF-8. Maybe there are some hints in the commit logs that indicate why `termencoding` is treated this way; I will leave that archeology to someone else, though.

The code path for handling `fileencoding` is different. It only forces UTF-8 for the “internal side” of the conversion (and only if a “Unicode” `encoding` is in effect).